# Group serializer results based on value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I'm fairly new to Django, so I can't tell if this is possible using a class based view, but I would like to group search results based on a value in the JSON returned from the query. Basically I want my results to go from this:

```
{
"id": "0038",
"attributes": [
    {
        "name": "State",
        "values": "CA"
    },
    {
        "name": "Areas",
        "values": "Value 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Areas",
        "values": "Value 2"
    },
    {
        "name": "Areas",
        "values": "Value 3"
    }]}
```

To this:

```
{"id": "0038",
"attributes": [
    {
        "name": "State Licenses",
        "values": "CA"
    },
    {
        "name": "Areas",
        "values": ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"]
    }]}
```

Each "name/values" pair is a separate row in a MySQL database. My models.py looks like:

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
```

While the serializer looks like:

```
class AttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='name')
    values = serializers.CharField(source='value')
    class Meta:
        model = models.Attribute
        fields= ('name','values')
```

Any idea how I can do that? ListSerializer seems like it might be a likely candidate, and by extension so does adding `many=True` but I don't think that provides the grouping behavior I want. Any ideas?

Comment: Your proposal won't work because a hashtable shouldn't have duplicate keys, which is `values` in your case.

Comment: If you want grouping, then default serializer might not be able to do that simply because you want customized result. You can write your own serializer.

Comment: Edited to clarify what JSON I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular `Serializer` - this is to say not a `ModelSerializer` - and override the [view's methods](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins) to create your own structure and pass it to the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `ListSerializer.to_representation`.  Read more about overriding `.to_representation` in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#advanced-serializer-usage).

```
def transform_data(data):
    result = {}
    for item in data:
        name, value = item['name'], item['value']
        if result.get(name):
            result[name].append(value) 
        else:
            result[name] = [value]
    return result


class AttributeListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = super(AttributeListSerializer, self).to_representation(data)
        # data is currently in this format:
        # [
        #     {"name": "State", "values": "CA"},
        #     {"name": "Areas", "values": "1"},
        # ]
        # transform_data can be updated to transform the data however you like...
        return transform_data(data)


class AttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='name')
    values = serializers.CharField(source='value')
    class Meta:
        model = models.Attribute
        fields= ('name','values')
        # the below is KEY
        list_serializer_class = AttributeListSerializer
```